# interpretation of keyword new in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

On the site of [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), I see the following sentence:

> This is a list of reserved keywords in C++. Since they are used by the language, these keywords are **not** available for **re-definition or overloading**.

Among the keywords, there is **new**. But I know that we can overload **new** in C++.
So the above citation is wrong or there is something else there for the keyword **new** ?

Comment: I suggest finding an alternate site to use for C++ refs... One with more credible reputation. This would be one, but many are available. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875057.aspx

Comment: @nixxbb What is wrong with cppreference.com?  It is much much better than cplusplus.com

Comment: Have you tried `void new() {}`?

Comment: @nixxbb, cppreference is simply the **best** C++ reference available online. And it is correct here, by the way.

Comment: @nixxbb: lol did you just assert that MSDN has a "more credible reputation" than cppreference?

Comment: @NathanOliver: cplusplus.com's reference section is actually _much_ better now than it used to be. A few years ago I agreed to a request from its owner to take down an article from my blog that declared it unfit for general use, and I don't regret having done so. Though the forums and tutorials are still dangerous purely because they're submitted by enthusiastic beginners and not peer reviewed (and this is true of any set of webpages with that model).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is good to know.  I had some bad experiences with it and because of those I found cppreference and never looked back.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Sadly I've had to make two corrections to cppreference.com over the past few months, and that's over relatively few visits.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit please make more, that's the point of it being a wiki! Your comment on valarray::operator= was influential in presenting LWG defects

Comment: @Cubbi: That's also the problem with it being a wiki :P (I don't know what comment you're referring to)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't overload `new`. You can overload `operator new`, which is the function that `new` calls to allocate memory before it constructs the object(s).

Comment: I mean new can only be an operator right? what is the purpose of making an operator as keyword? If we don't stipulate "new" as a keyword in the C++ standard, we can still use new to do what it does now, just consider new as a predefined function, right?

Comment: @gab -- no, the keyword `new` can't be implemented as a function. It has to know about types and their constructors, which is the responsibility of the compiler.